# how to replicate a href from javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, href

i have a link

```
<a id="cartLink" href="https://site.foxycart.com/cart?cart=checkout" >Test</a>
```

when you click on this link it loads up a popup dialog (it doesn't change to a new window location, etc)

i now want to generate that url on the fly so i thought i would use jquery and something like this:

```
 $('#cartLink').live('click', function () {
     var count = $("#abc").text();

     var url = "https://site.foxycart.com/cart?cart=view&MyCount=" + count;

     NOW SOMEHOW REPLICATE THE SAME WAY THE HREF WOULD HAVE WORKED

});
```

so as you  can see i can't use window.open(), etc. what is the best way to replicate the same behavior as if i would have clicked on the link with the href set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your selected has selected any element with id #cartLink, you'll be able to refer to it as $(this) from within your function.

After the var url = ... ; write the following:

```
$(this).attr('href', url);
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
 $('#cartLink').live('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();//This will prevent the default behavior of the anchor.
     var count = $("#abc").text();
     var url = "https://site.foxycart.com/cart?cart=view&MyCount=" + count;
     window.location.href = url;//It will redirect to "url" in the current window.
 });
```